# XCode Warning: "/* within block comment"

Tags: ios, xcode

I really like to temporary enable and disable code parts by commenting them this way:

```
/*
some code
/**/
```

(Mind the

> /**/

instead of

> */

at the end)

However, XCode keeps giving me the warning:

```
/* within block comment
```

Is there any way to "custom-disable" specific warnings?

WHY? I will tell you why: Because I can easily take it in and out with only one character, without having to scroll down the block to take the "*/ in and out.

Comment: Umm... just only use a `*/`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a very nice alternative to:

```
/*    
some code
/**/
```

You can just use this variant:

```
/*
some code
//*/
```

to achieve the same goal without any Xcode warnings!

Comment: @trojanfoe you don't want to define flags for each and every block of comments used during development, your answer is good for the production version, this one answers particular question more related to development process.

Comment: @A-Live These aren't comments; this commented-out code.  Using flags (even ones like `0`) makes it more obvious that this is commented-out code rather than a comment.  This solution is error prone as you have to remember that `//*/` is used to terminate the comment.  In short it's bad and not at all "nice", let alone "very nice".

Comment: @trojanfoe appreciate your intent to teach others better "coding" style, however the question is very precise in terms of the final `*/` to be ignored if `/*` is removed. Understanding of the block structure might be achieved by indentation or internal comments. If used correctly, that is much better than `cmmd(ctrl)+/` widely used at IDE's.

Comment: @A-Live Well the OP did actually say that he wanted to enable/disable specific lumps of code by changing one character.  I've provided a better solution which is more visible to the programmer (especially in 3 months time when you come back to the code).  However people are free to do whatever they like with their code and only experience will teach them better methods and the only way to gain experience to do things wrong :)

Comment: Easier than finding that obscure CLANG flag that's for sure... I did actually set the compiler flag but CLANG is apparently separate from that so my IDE would still show a warning. Which is annoying because other ObjC warnings are critical, so you never want to ignore them.

Answer (score 8):

When I want to temporarily remove a block of code I use:

```
#if 0
somecode();
#endif
```

Which avoids this issue and is easy to spot later.

If I want to later temporarily re-enable that code, then I simply flip the `0` to `1`:

```
#if 1
somecode();
#endif
```

However if this enable/disable needs to be more visible, and easier to control, then I use a constant defined at the top of the source file instead:

```
#define SOME_FANCY_FEATURE 1

...

#if SOME_FANCY_FEATURE
somecode();
#endif // SOME_FANCY_FEATURE
```

Comment: Does not answer my question, but a nice alternative though. Worth an up vote.

Comment: @user1423640 I'm afraid there is no answer to your question, just alternatives. You are introducing syntax errors into your code doing what you are doing.

Comment: @trojanfoe your solution SEEMS effective, but actually is far worse. It fails hard when you have multiple nested chunks of code being commented out (I encounter this often when debugging/refactoring large monolithic projects that are long overdue an overhaul - i.e. real-world apps :)). The problem is that Xcode has very poor support for #if blocks that are nested: after a couple of nestings, it breaks the  syntax hilighter and formatter FOR THE WHOLE CLASS, and it can never get the layout correct. If Xcode were better, your approach would work. In general, it only works for trivial cases :(

Comment: @trojanfoe also, FWIW - I use your approach frequently. Especially in IDE's that are not as stupid as Xcode! And for simple cases I agree it's perfect. But in general ... it's not good enough :(

Answer (score 5):

The real answer for me (just disabling an XCode warning, without changing any line in legacy code) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046102/540639
**Apple LLVM 6.0 Custom Compiler Flags -> Other Warning Flags -> -Wno-comment**