# Disable "/* within block comment" warning in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I frequently need multiple nested multiline (or "partial line") comments while developing.

Xcode recently introduced possibly the world's most annoying Warning - and it's forced me to disable "warnings as errors". I'm guessing this warning is to catch the extremely rare case of when someone typos and causes a block comment to have no end - but IME there are many many other problems that will cause that will reveal it very quickly.

Some examples:

```
/* removed while debugging the BARFOO
-(void) aMethod
{
[self methodCall:7.0 /* needed to FOO the BAR: */ * self.multiplier * /* double for hi-res:*/ 2.0];
}
*/
```

and:

```
/* removed while debugging the BARFOO

/** This method has DOCUMENTATION
*/
-(void) aDocumentedMethod
{
...
}

-(void) aMethod
{
/** internally, we have to BAR BAR the FOOFOO.
1. BAR
2. BARBAR
3. Finally, FOOOFOO
*/
...complex lines of source here...
}
*/
```

and of course, the very simple double-comment-out while debugging.

But I can't find a place in Xcode5 to disable this warning - it doesn't seem to exist in any of the listed warnings :( ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode Warning: "/\* within block comment"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774127/xcode-warning-within-block-comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the warning code, do a build, go to the "Log Navigator", select a build, expand the build log:

[image]

Once you're looking at the details of your build log, you'll see the warning code listed there. In this case, you'll see the warning is `-Wcomment`.

---

Note, this helps you identify the warning you inquired about (the "/* within block comment" warning), but it doesn't change the behavior of nested `/* ... */` comments.

I personally use Abizern's technique for quickly commenting large blocks. Alternatively, you could use

```
#if 0
```

and

```
#endif
```

(which you can nest) when commenting out your block

Comment: Excellent. It took me a few attempts to add the warning. In Xcode5, you have to find "Other Compiler Warnings", and add a line including the -W, i.e. appears in Xcode (after editing as a line):  "Other Compiler Warnings = -Wno-comment"

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `//` for comments everywhere. That way you don't get this warning.

`/` is also compatible with doxygen type comments, you don't need to use the `/**` version.

And Xcode supports this syntax. If you select a region you can toggle the comments with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: I think you mean // comments?

Comment: How exactly do you do inline comments without /* ?

Comment: Also: massive multiline // comments are much less readable than using the (standard!) /** javadoc comments. I'd much rather fix the problem than make my source code harder to work with just to workaround an IDE bug :(.

Comment: and: many projects (or maintainers) will replace // multiline comments with /* */ on checkin anyway, so I don't see this as a workable solution :(

Comment: Inline comments when sending messages to objects? Didn't notice that, not my thing.

Comment: If you only work with straightforward code and well-designed APIs, I wouldn't expect to need it ;). It's the mix of bad APIs, systems that get added to and added to many times over the years, and hacks-upon-hacks ... leaving the new programmers with some hairy signatures to deal with! :)