# Xcode: suppressing specific warning

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

To disable compiler warning I go to **Project** -> **Target** -> **Build Settings** and add flag

```
-w
```

for specific file. This flag disables **all** warnings.

But my intention is to exclude a specific warning, not all.
I found a solution like this:

```
-Wnodeprecated-declarations
```

where **deprecated-declarations** is a specific warning *id*.

How can I determine which *id* has a specific warning? (In my Xcode only warning description is displayed)

Comment: Go to the log navigator and open up the transcript. It will show you the -W code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046102/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554532/1271826. See https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev21d56ecd4.

Comment: @Rob, but what about warnings like: */Pods/Nimble/Sources/Nimble/Matchers/MatcherProtocols.swift:15:11: 'Matcher' is deprecated: Use to Predicate instead* ? Nimble is an external library and I would like hide such warnings. Flag *-w* for *MatcherProtocols.swift* does not work.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to show us what the full transcript looked like.